# Ставится ли запятая в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

"Как только это произойдет, мы придем(,) и вы должны будете пойти с нами."
Нужна ли тут запятая?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если бы не было связи между "мы придём" и "вы пойдёте с нами", то "как только это произойдёт" просто объединяло бы во времени два независимых события, и запятая была бы не нужна. (Как только это произойдёт, мы придём и уйдут пришедшие до нас.) Но здесь причинная связь: второе возможно только при условии первого (с нами можно пойти только если мы придём), поэтому нужна запятая.

Comment: Согласна, что смысл меняется оттого, как разобрать предложение - СПП с однородными придаточными или сложное с сочинением и подчинением. Только право выбирать всё же за автором. Что он хотел сказать - только он знает. А здесь и то и другое возможно.

Answer (score 2):

"Как только это произойдет, мы придем, и вы должны будете пойти с нами."

Здесь описываются две ситуации, и запятая формально должна быть поставлена. Но вот структура предложения не очень удачная.

Если убрать последнее предложение, то получается: Как только это произойдет, мы придем. Лучше было бы: Мы придем, как только это произойдет. Казалось бы, разницы нет, но во втором случае главное предложение в большей степени независимое, а в первом варианте мы имеем взаимообусловленность главного и придаточного

Поэтому предлагается такое оформление: Мы придем, как только это произойдет, и вы должны будете пойти с нами.

Answer (score 1):

Да, запятая нужна. Это ССП.

Comment: Только не ССП, а СПП

Answer (score 1):

Запятая между двумя предложениями: каждое со своим подл. и сказ.

Comment: Спс.......И еще раз спс.